# Swift: Cannot assign a value of type 'int' to a value of type 'int?' Error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm starting to learn swift, but ran into an error. Ive just created a very simple app from a course I'm following, that calculates a cats ages based on what the user enters. The first version of the app just times what the user enters by 7, which i managed todo no problem. I thought I would have a play with what I've written and change it todo this:

- 1st human year = 15 cat years
- 2nd human year = +10
- 3rd human year = +4
- 4th human year = +4
- 5th human year = +4

so on..

e.g. a 4 year old cat would be 33 in cat years.

So I want my results label to say You're cat is 33 in cat years

This is the code I've written:

```
    @IBAction func findAge(sender: AnyObject) {

    var enteredAge = enterAge.text.toInt()

    if enteredAge = 1 {

        var catYears = 15

        resultLabel.text = "You're cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

    } else if enteredAge = 2 {

        var catYears = 25

        resultLabel.text = "You're cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

    } else {

        var catYears = (15 + 25) + (enteredAge - 2) * 4

        resultLabel.text = "You're cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

    }

}

@IBOutlet weak var enterAge: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
```

This error I'm getting is on the line 17 "if enteredAge = 1 {" it states this "cannot assign a value of type 'int' to a value of type 'int?'"

I don't really understand why this value cannot be a integer, any help would be great.

Comment: Comparison in Swift is done with `==`, not with `=`.

Comment: fantastic! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error ([as I said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614645/swift-cannot-assign-a-value-of-type-int-to-a-value-of-type-int-error#comment51179359_31614645)) is that you mixed up the *assignment operator* `=`
and the *equality operator* `==`. The comparison should be

```
if enteredAge == 1 { ... }
```

The next problem is ([as keithbhunter already stated in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614645/swift-cannot-assign-a-value-of-type-int-to-a-value-of-type-int-error/31614703#31614703)), 
`toInt()` returns an *optional* which is `nil` if the string is not a
valid integer, and you should use *optional binding*:

```
if let enteredAge = enterAge.text.toInt() {
   // compute cat years ... 
} else {
   // report invalid input ...
}
```

*Additional notes:*

- All your variables in that method can be declared as *constants*
  with `let`.
- There are 3 identical assignments `resultLabel.text = ...`, this can
  be simplified.
- Instead of `if ... else if ... else` you could use a `switch` statement.

Then your method would look like this:

```
if let enteredAge = enterAge.text.toInt() {
    let catYears : Int
    switch(enteredAge) {
    case 1:
        catYears = 15
    case 2:
        catYears = 25
    default:
        catYears = (15 + 25) + (enteredAge - 2) * 4
    }
    resultLabel.text = "You're cat is \(catYears) in cat years"
} else {
    resultLabel.text = "Please enter a valid number"
}
```

An alternative would be to use the *conditional operator* `?:` 
(sometimes also called *ternary operator*):

```
if let enteredAge = enterAge.text.toInt() {
    let catYears = enteredAge == 1 ? 15 :
                enteredAge == 2 ? 25 : (15 + 25) + (enteredAge - 2) * 4
    resultLabel.text = "You're cat is \(catYears) in cat years"
} else {
    resultLabel.text = "Please enter a valid number"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure of the `toInt()` method, but I am going to guess that method returns an `Int?`. This means that it can return nil if it cannot convert the string to an int. You should unwrap this value to handle nil cases.

```
if var enteredAge = enterAge.text.toInt() {
    // the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Ok I've tried that, but I get a different error but at the same line. "Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'int'"

Answer (score 1):

You have already assigned the value to the `enteredAge` variable like follows:

```
var enteredAge = enterAge.text.toInt()
```

So, you cannot do assignment on the place of this if expression. and you need to have condition on the if expression as follows.

```
if enteredAge == 1 {

    var catYears = 15

    resultLabel.text = "You're cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

}
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

should look like this  :

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    var inputYears = textField.text.toInt()!
    if inputYears == 1 {
    var catOld = 15
    result.text = "Your cat is \(catOld) years old"
    }
    else if inputYears == 2 {
    var catOld = 25
    result.text = "Your cat is \(catOld) years old"
    }
    else {var catOld = (15+25) + (inputYears - 2)*4
    result.text = "Your cat is \(catOld) years old"
    }
```